# android application is crashing after adding abmob dependencies in gradle

Tags: java, android, crash, admob, build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 29

    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "arvindo.bassboster"

        minSdkVersion 16

        targetSdkVersion 29
    }

    dependencies {

        //noinspection GradleCompatible

        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

// ... other dependencies
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {

            minifyEnabled false

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {

   exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'

        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.0.1'

    })

    //noinspection GradleCompatible

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'


    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //noinspection GradleCompatible

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
}
```

app is working well after removing the Admob dependencies,

log

```
2020-04-15 15:09:05.847 560-560/? I/hwservicemanager: getTransport: Cannot find entry vendor.qti.hardware.iop@2.0::IIop/default in either framework or device manifest.
2020-04-15 15:09:05.851 1051-31588/? D/AudioPolicyService: UidPolicy::onUidStateChanged() UID=99369 procState=20
2020-04-15 15:09:05.853 20651-20753/? I/DCS-BackgroundAppData: sendAppBgEvent: has no pkgName=com.sonyliv
2020-04-15 15:09:05.885 560-560/? I/hwservicemanager: getTransport: Cannot find entry vendor.qti.hardware.iop@2.0::IIop/default in either framework or device manifest.
2020-04-15 15:09:05.887 4347-4347/? I/Zygote: Process 29064 exited cleanly (0)
2020-04-15 15:09:05.887 560-560/? E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { find } for interface=vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker::IServicetracker sid=u:r:system_server:s0 pid=1808 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:default_android_hwservice:s0 tclass=hwservice_manager permissive=0
2020-04-15 15:09:05.890 20651-20753/? I/DCS-BackgroundAppData: sendAppBgEvent: has no pkgName=com.sonyliv
2020-04-15 15:09:05.928 1808-2130/? D/KernelCpuUidUserSysTimeReader: Removing uids 99006-99006
2020-04-15 15:09:05.929 1808-2130/? D/OppoBatteryStatsImpl: Got readings for an isolated uid with no mapping: 99006
2020-04-15 15:09:05.988 4508-4508/? D/OppoNecManager: notifyOrigSignalStrengthChanged slotId:0
2020-04-15 15:09:05.989 1808-6779/? D/OppoNecService: reportNecEvent.slotId:0,eventId:8000
2020-04-15 15:09:05.992 4497-4497/? D/OppoNecEventListener: handleNecEventReport:8000
2020-04-15 15:09:07.772 4508-4508/? D/OppoNecManager: notifyOrigSignalStrengthChanged slotId:0
2020-04-15 15:09:07.773 1808-6779/? D/OppoNecService: reportNecEvent.slotId:0,eventId:8000
2020-04-15 15:09:07.776 4497-4497/? D/OppoNecEventListener: handleNecEventReport:8000
2020-04-15 15:09:09.017 30968-31015/? I/WorkerManager: dispose()
2020-04-15 15:09:10.194 1808-3757/? D/WifiClientModeImpl: Adjust rssi from -21 to -35
2020-04-15 15:09:10.314 1808-1808/? D/OppoPowerMonitor: Receive broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
2020-04-15 15:09:10.318 20498-20498/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
2020-04-15 15:09:10.628 1808-2015/? W/Watchdog: !@WatchDog_27033
2020-04-15 15:09:15.196 1808-3757/? D/WifiClientModeImpl: Adjust rssi from -18 to -35
2020-04-15 15:09:15.498 1808-1808/? D/OppoPowerMonitor: Receive broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
2020-04-15 15:09:15.503 20498-20498/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
2020-04-15 15:09:15.639 27558-27559/? E/rutils: releaseProcess gCount = 3
```

Comment: Can you tell us which gradle file is which? And the logcat doesn't contain any crash info. Can you check that again?

Comment: build.gradle (module app): After adding this "implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.0.1'. app is crashing and not opening.

Comment: When you try to open it, do you see errors in the logcat? Perhaps with a stacktrace as well? And don't put it inside the androidTestImplementation block!

Answer (score 0):

You can't put the dependency inside the `androidTestImplementation` block. That makes no sense. Do it as follows:

```
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        // DONT PUT IT HERE!
    })

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.0.1' // <-- put it here

    //noinspection GradleCompatible

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'


    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //noinspection GradleCompatible

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I modified as you suggested and still, the app is crashing and again when I remove "implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.0.1", It's runs flawlessly.

Comment: @arvindersingh what happens in the logcat? Do you see a lot of red errors?

Comment: 2020-04-15 15:52:26.398 1069-1069/? E/Layer: [Surface(name=AppWindowToken{8e74a6d token=Token{fcf1284 ActivityRecord{88d2097 u0 com.oppo.launcher/.Launcher t1}}})/@0xd41befc - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found
2020-04-15 15:52:26.398 1069-1069/? E/Layer: [Surface(name=AppWindowToken{182fe95 token=Token{485de4c ActivityRecord{5441e7f u0 arvindo.bassboster/com.bassbooster.android_simple_eq.MainActivity t4433}}})/@0xdfca35a - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found

Comment: 2020-04-15 15:53:32.064 10636-10700/? E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.UCMobile.intl
2020-04-15 15:53:32.065 10636-10700/? E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
2020-04-15 15:53:32.066 10636-10700/? E/Perf: Fail to get file list oat
2020-04-15 15:53:32.066 10636-10700/? E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array

Comment: 2020-04-15 15:53:31.901 560-560/? E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { find } for interface=vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker::IServicetracker sid=u:r:system_server:s0 pid=1808 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:default_android_hwservice:s0 tclass=hwservice_manager permissive=0
2020-04-15 15:53:31.903 560-560/? E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { find } for interface=vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker::IServicetracker sid=u:r:system_server:s0 pid=1808 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:default_android_hwservice:s0 tclass=hwservice_manager permissive=0

Comment: 2020-04-15 15:53:31.829 560-560/? E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { find } for interface=vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker::IServicetracker sid=u:r:system_server:s0 pid=1808 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:default_android_hwservice:s0 tclass=hwservice_manager permissive=0

Comment: 2020-04-15 15:53:31.046 10636-10636/? E/ckgroundProces: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x20000
2020-04-15 15:53:31.060 10636-10636/? E/ckgroundProces: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2020-04-15 15:53:31.093 560-560/? E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { find } for interface=vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker::IServicetracker sid=u:r:system_server:s0 pid=1808 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:default_android_hwservice:s0 tclass=hwservice_manager permissive=0

Comment: 2020-04-15 15:49:21.896 1808-6710/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
2020-04-15 15:49:22.004 560-560/? E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { find } for interface=vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker::IServicetracker sid=u:r:system_server:s0 pid=1808 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:default_android_hwservice:s0 tclass=hwservice_manager permissive=0
2020-04-15 15:49:22.006 560-560/? E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { find } for interface=vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker::IServicetracker